# Fazer calculo de level e experiência com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um código que pegue o valor da base de experiência (`base`) e subtrair pela experiência ganha (`bn`), então o código retorna quantos níveis ele subiu (`up`) e a `exp` restante.

Estou tendo problemas em fazer com que ao "upar" a base passe a ser correspondente ao do level 2. Eu consegui fazer apenas com `if/else`, contudo ficou muito código e a página HTML do fórum não suportou.

#### Código

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calcular").click(function() {
    var base;
    var lv = $("#level").val();
    var tp = $("#tipo").val();
    var bt = $("#batalha").val();
    var bn = $("#numero").val();
    var res = $("#resultado").val();



    if(lv==1) {
      base=10;
    }
    if(lv==2) {
      base=30;
    }


    up=0;


    while(bn>=base){

      lv++;
      $("#lv").val(lv)

      bn= bn-base;
      up++;
      $("#up").val(up);

    }



  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  color:#000;
  font-size:11pt;
}

select {
  width:160px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
}

input {
  width:152px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
  text-align:right;
}

#calcular {
  width:160px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#666;
  color:#fff;
}

#exp {
  text-align:center;
}
#exp2 {
  text-align:center;
}
#exp3 {
  text-align:center;
}

td {
  padding-right:10px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pokemyrpg.forumeiros.com/24899.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form>
  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Informe o Nível:
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="level">
            <option value="1">Nível 1</option>
            <option value="2">Nível 2</option>
            <option value="3">Nível 3</option>
            <option value="4">Nível 4</option>
            <option value="5">Nível 5</option>
            <option value="6">Nível 6</option>
            <option value="7">Nível 7</option>
            <option value="8">Nível 8</option>
            <option value="9">Nível 9</option>
            <option value="10">Nível 10</option>
            <option value="11">Nível 11</option>
            <option value="12">Nível 12</option>
            <option value="13">Nível 13</option>
            <option value="14">Nível 14</option>
            <option value="15">Nível 15</option>
            <option value="16">Nível 16</option>
            <option value="17">Nível 17</option>
            <option value="18">Nível 18</option>
            <option value="19">Nível 19</option>
            <option value="20">Nível 20</option>
            <option value="21">Nível 21</option>
            <option value="22">Nível 22</option>
            <option value="23">Nível 23</option>
            <option value="24">Nível 24</option>
            <option value="25">Nível 25</option>
            <option value="26">Nível 26</option>
            <option value="27">Nível 27</option>
            <option value="28">Nível 28</option>
            <option value="29">Nível 29</option>
            <option value="30">Nível 30</option>
            <option value="31">Nível 31</option>
            <option value="32">Nível 32</option>
            <option value="33">Nível 33</option>
            <option value="34">Nível 34</option>
            <option value="35">Nível 35</option>
            <option value="36">Nível 36</option>
            <option value="37">Nível 37</option>
            <option value="38">Nível 38</option>
            <option value="39">Nível 39</option>
            <option value="40">Nível 40</option>
            <option value="41">Nível 41</option>
            <option value="42">Nível 42</option>
            <option value="43">Nível 43</option>
            <option value="44">Nível 44</option>
            <option value="45">Nível 45</option>
            <option value="46">Nível 46</option>
            <option value="47">Nível 47</option>
            <option value="48">Nível 48</option>
            <option value="49">Nível 49</option>
            <option value="50">Nível 50</option>
            <option value="51">Nível 51</option>
            <option value="52">Nível 52</option>
            <option value="53">Nível 53</option>
            <option value="54">Nível 54</option>
            <option value="55">Nível 55</option>
            <option value="56">Nível 56</option>
            <option value="57">Nível 57</option>
            <option value="58">Nível 58</option>
            <option value="59">Nível 59</option>
            <option value="60">Nível 60</option>
            <option value="61">Nível 61</option>
            <option value="62">Nível 62</option>
            <option value="63">Nível 63</option>
            <option value="64">Nível 64</option>
            <option value="65">Nível 65</option>
            <option value="66">Nível 66</option>
            <option value="67">Nível 67</option>
            <option value="68">Nível 68</option>
            <option value="69">Nível 69</option>
            <option value="70">Nível 70</option>
            <option value="71">Nível 71</option>
            <option value="72">Nível 72</option>
            <option value="73">Nível 73</option>
            <option value="74">Nível 74</option>
            <option value="75">Nível 75</option>
            <option value="76">Nível 76</option>
            <option value="77">Nível 77</option>
            <option value="78">Nível 78</option>
            <option value="79">Nível 79</option>
            <option value="80">Nível 80</option>
            <option value="81">Nível 81</option>
            <option value="82">Nível 82</option>
            <option value="83">Nível 83</option>
            <option value="84">Nível 84</option>
            <option value="85">Nível 85</option>
            <option value="86">Nível 86</option>
            <option value="87">Nível 87</option>
            <option value="88">Nível 88</option>
            <option value="89">Nível 89</option>
            <option value="90">Nível 90</option>
            <option value="91">Nível 91</option>
            <option value="92">Nível 92</option>
            <option value="93">Nível 93</option>
            <option value="94">Nível 94</option>
            <option value="95">Nível 95</option>
            <option value="96">Nível 96</option>
            <option value="97">Nível 97</option>
            <option value="98">Nível 98</option>
            <option value="99">Nível 99</option>
            <option value="100">Nível 100</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          Exp ganha:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input max="25" min="0" step="1" pattern="0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25" value="0" type="text" id="numero" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Up!" type="button" id="calcular" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Níveis upados:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="up" type="text" />
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Mais informações:

Estou tentando fazer que quando eu coloco `40` de `exp`, ele suba 2 levels, sendo que a base do level 1 é `10` e a base do level 2 é `40`. Mas quando eu coloco `40` de `exp` ele upa 4 levels, sendo que ele está considerando apenas a base do level 1 que é `10` (10 * 4 = 40).

Assim, ao colocar `40` de `exp` ele deve testar se é maior que a base (no caso `10`), se sim ele upa para o level 2. Ao upar para o level 2 a base passa a ser `30`, logo ele deveria testar se a exp restante é maior que 30, se for vai upar outro level.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Está bem confusa a explicação, é uma regra de potenciação que você quer? tipo `var base = Math.pow(level, 10) ;`

Comment: O que seria isso que você chame de **base**?

Comment: Porque do nível 1 (base 10) ele pula para nível 2 (base 30) e muda experiencia ele vai pro nível 4, que bagunça... tá bem difícil de entender a sua lógica.

Comment: Olha minha resposta @FábioFerreira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom eu não entendi qual o conceito direito, mas em teoria, eu acho que é isso que você precisa:

```
<title>Calculadora de EXP</title><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css">

body {
   font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
   color:#000;
   font-size:11pt;
}

select {
   width:160px;
   border:1px solid #333;
   padding:3px;
}

input {
   width:152px;
   border:1px solid #333;
   padding:3px;
   text-align:right;
}

#calcular {
   width:160px;
   text-align:center;
   background:#666;
   color:#fff;
}

#exp {
   text-align:center;
}
#exp2 {
   text-align:center;
}
#exp3 {
   text-align:center;
}

td {
   padding-right:10px;
   text-align:right;
}

</style>
<script src="http://pokemyrpg.forumeiros.com/24899.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#calcular").click(function() {
      var lv = $("#level").val();
      var tp = $("#tipo").val();
      var bt = $("#batalha").val();
      var exp = $("#exp").val();
      var res = $("#resultado").val();
      var itens = getCalcBase(lv, exp);
      //console.log(itens);
      $("#up").val(itens['levelup']);
      $("#lv").val(itens['exp_restante']);

      if (itens['exp_atual'] < itens['exp_required']) {
          alert('experiência requerida para esse nível: '+itens['exp_required']);
      }

      if (itens['exp_atual'] >= itens['exp_required_last_nivel']) {
          alert('você passou de nível: '+itens['levelup']);
       }
   });
});

function getCalcBase(selectedLevel, exp) {
    var expAtual = exp;
    var totalLevels = 100;   
    var levelup = selectedLevel;
    var base = [];
    var itens = [];
    var baseVal = 10;

    for (var level=1; level<=(totalLevels - selectedLevel); level++) {
        base[level] = baseVal;
        baseVal *= 4; 
    }

    var exp_required = base[selectedLevel];
    var lastLevelExp = exp_required * 4;

    if (expAtual >= lastLevelExp) {
      while (exp >= base[selectedLevel]) {
        exp -= base[selectedLevel];
        if (exp >= base[levelup]) {
           levelup++;
        }
      }
    }

   itens['exp_restante'] = exp;
   itens['exp_atual'] = expAtual;
   itens['levelup'] = levelup;
   itens['exp_required'] = exp_required;
   itens['exp_required_last_nivel'] = lastLevelExp ;
   return itens;
}
</script> 
<form>
   <table border="0">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Informe o Nível:
            </td>
            <td>
               <select id="level">
<option value="1">Nível 1</option>
<option value="2">Nível 2</option>
<option value="3">Nível 3</option>
<option value="4">Nível 4</option>
<option value="5">Nível 5</option>
<option value="6">Nível 6</option>
<option value="7">Nível 7</option>
<option value="8">Nível 8</option>
<option value="9">Nível 9</option>
<option value="10">Nível 10</option>
<option value="11">Nível 11</option>
<option value="12">Nível 12</option>
<option value="13">Nível 13</option>
<option value="14">Nível 14</option>
<option value="15">Nível 15</option>
<option value="16">Nível 16</option>
<option value="17">Nível 17</option>
<option value="18">Nível 18</option>
<option value="19">Nível 19</option>
<option value="20">Nível 20</option>
<option value="21">Nível 21</option>
<option value="22">Nível 22</option>
<option value="23">Nível 23</option>
<option value="24">Nível 24</option>
<option value="25">Nível 25</option>
<option value="26">Nível 26</option>
<option value="27">Nível 27</option>
<option value="28">Nível 28</option>
<option value="29">Nível 29</option>
<option value="30">Nível 30</option>
<option value="31">Nível 31</option>
<option value="32">Nível 32</option>
<option value="33">Nível 33</option>
<option value="34">Nível 34</option>
<option value="35">Nível 35</option>
<option value="36">Nível 36</option>
<option value="37">Nível 37</option>
<option value="38">Nível 38</option>
<option value="39">Nível 39</option>
<option value="40">Nível 40</option>
<option value="41">Nível 41</option>
<option value="42">Nível 42</option>
<option value="43">Nível 43</option>
<option value="44">Nível 44</option>
<option value="45">Nível 45</option>
<option value="46">Nível 46</option>
<option value="47">Nível 47</option>
<option value="48">Nível 48</option>
<option value="49">Nível 49</option>
<option value="50">Nível 50</option>
<option value="51">Nível 51</option>
<option value="52">Nível 52</option>
<option value="53">Nível 53</option>
<option value="54">Nível 54</option>
<option value="55">Nível 55</option>
<option value="56">Nível 56</option>
<option value="57">Nível 57</option>
<option value="58">Nível 58</option>
<option value="59">Nível 59</option>
<option value="60">Nível 60</option>
<option value="61">Nível 61</option>
<option value="62">Nível 62</option>
<option value="63">Nível 63</option>
<option value="64">Nível 64</option>
<option value="65">Nível 65</option>
<option value="66">Nível 66</option>
<option value="67">Nível 67</option>
<option value="68">Nível 68</option>
<option value="69">Nível 69</option>
<option value="70">Nível 70</option>
<option value="71">Nível 71</option>
<option value="72">Nível 72</option>
<option value="73">Nível 73</option>
<option value="74">Nível 74</option>
<option value="75">Nível 75</option>
<option value="76">Nível 76</option>
<option value="77">Nível 77</option>
<option value="78">Nível 78</option>
<option value="79">Nível 79</option>
<option value="80">Nível 80</option>
<option value="81">Nível 81</option>
<option value="82">Nível 82</option>
<option value="83">Nível 83</option>
<option value="84">Nível 84</option>
<option value="85">Nível 85</option>
<option value="86">Nível 86</option>
<option value="87">Nível 87</option>
<option value="88">Nível 88</option>
<option value="89">Nível 89</option>
<option value="90">Nível 90</option>
<option value="91">Nível 91</option>
<option value="92">Nível 92</option>
<option value="93">Nível 93</option>
<option value="94">Nível 94</option>
<option value="95">Nível 95</option>
<option value="96">Nível 96</option>
<option value="97">Nível 97</option>
<option value="98">Nível 98</option>
<option value="99">Nível 99</option>
<option value="100">Nível 100</option>
</select>
            </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>
               Exp ganha:
            </td>
            <td>
               <input max="25" min="0" step="1" pattern="0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25" value="0" type="text" id="exp" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input value="Up!" type="button" id="calcular" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Níveis upados:
            </td>
            <td>
               <input id="up" type="text" />
            </td></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Exatamente! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado também a todos os que tentaram ajudar. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Coloca os if dentro do while para que a base seja atualizada a cada iteração:

```html
<title>Calculadora de EXP</title><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css">
    
    body {
       font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
       color:#000;
       font-size:11pt;
    }
    
    select {
       width:160px;
       border:1px solid #333;
       padding:3px;
    }
    
    input {
       width:152px;
       border:1px solid #333;
       padding:3px;
       text-align:right;
    }
    
    #calcular {
       width:160px;
       text-align:center;
       background:#666;
       color:#fff;
    }
    
    #exp {
       text-align:center;
    }
    #exp2 {
       text-align:center;
    }
    #exp3 {
       text-align:center;
    }
    
    td {
       padding-right:10px;
       text-align:right;
    }
    
    </style><script src="http://pokemyrpg.forumeiros.com/24899.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#calcular").click(function() {
          var base;
          var lv = $("#level").val();
          var tp = $("#tipo").val();
          var bt = $("#batalha").val();
          var bn = $("#numero").val();
          var res = $("#resultado").val();
          
    
          
             if(lv==1) { base=10; }
             if(lv==2) { base=30; }
             
          
          var up=0;
             
          
          while(bn>=base){             
             lv++;
             $("#lv").val(lv);
             
             bn = bn-base;
            up++;
            $("#up").val(up);
            if(lv==1) { base=10; }
            if(lv==2) { base=30; }             
          }
          
          
          
       });
    });
    
    </script> 
    <form>
       <table border="0">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>
                   Informe o Nível:
                </td>
                <td>
                   <select id="level">
    <option value="1">Nível 1</option>
    <option value="2">Nível 2</option>
    <option value="3">Nível 3</option>
    <option value="4">Nível 4</option>
    <option value="5">Nível 5</option>
    <option value="6">Nível 6</option>
    <option value="7">Nível 7</option>
    <option value="8">Nível 8</option>
    <option value="9">Nível 9</option>
    <option value="10">Nível 10</option>
    <option value="11">Nível 11</option>
    <option value="12">Nível 12</option>
    <option value="13">Nível 13</option>
    <option value="14">Nível 14</option>
    <option value="15">Nível 15</option>
    <option value="16">Nível 16</option>
    <option value="17">Nível 17</option>
    <option value="18">Nível 18</option>
    <option value="19">Nível 19</option>
    <option value="20">Nível 20</option>
    <option value="21">Nível 21</option>
    <option value="22">Nível 22</option>
    <option value="23">Nível 23</option>
    <option value="24">Nível 24</option>
    <option value="25">Nível 25</option>
    <option value="26">Nível 26</option>
    <option value="27">Nível 27</option>
    <option value="28">Nível 28</option>
    <option value="29">Nível 29</option>
    <option value="30">Nível 30</option>
    <option value="31">Nível 31</option>
    <option value="32">Nível 32</option>
    <option value="33">Nível 33</option>
    <option value="34">Nível 34</option>
    <option value="35">Nível 35</option>
    <option value="36">Nível 36</option>
    <option value="37">Nível 37</option>
    <option value="38">Nível 38</option>
    <option value="39">Nível 39</option>
    <option value="40">Nível 40</option>
    <option value="41">Nível 41</option>
    <option value="42">Nível 42</option>
    <option value="43">Nível 43</option>
    <option value="44">Nível 44</option>
    <option value="45">Nível 45</option>
    <option value="46">Nível 46</option>
    <option value="47">Nível 47</option>
    <option value="48">Nível 48</option>
    <option value="49">Nível 49</option>
    <option value="50">Nível 50</option>
    <option value="51">Nível 51</option>
    <option value="52">Nível 52</option>
    <option value="53">Nível 53</option>
    <option value="54">Nível 54</option>
    <option value="55">Nível 55</option>
    <option value="56">Nível 56</option>
    <option value="57">Nível 57</option>
    <option value="58">Nível 58</option>
    <option value="59">Nível 59</option>
    <option value="60">Nível 60</option>
    <option value="61">Nível 61</option>
    <option value="62">Nível 62</option>
    <option value="63">Nível 63</option>
    <option value="64">Nível 64</option>
    <option value="65">Nível 65</option>
    <option value="66">Nível 66</option>
    <option value="67">Nível 67</option>
    <option value="68">Nível 68</option>
    <option value="69">Nível 69</option>
    <option value="70">Nível 70</option>
    <option value="71">Nível 71</option>
    <option value="72">Nível 72</option>
    <option value="73">Nível 73</option>
    <option value="74">Nível 74</option>
    <option value="75">Nível 75</option>
    <option value="76">Nível 76</option>
    <option value="77">Nível 77</option>
    <option value="78">Nível 78</option>
    <option value="79">Nível 79</option>
    <option value="80">Nível 80</option>
    <option value="81">Nível 81</option>
    <option value="82">Nível 82</option>
    <option value="83">Nível 83</option>
    <option value="84">Nível 84</option>
    <option value="85">Nível 85</option>
    <option value="86">Nível 86</option>
    <option value="87">Nível 87</option>
    <option value="88">Nível 88</option>
    <option value="89">Nível 89</option>
    <option value="90">Nível 90</option>
    <option value="91">Nível 91</option>
    <option value="92">Nível 92</option>
    <option value="93">Nível 93</option>
    <option value="94">Nível 94</option>
    <option value="95">Nível 95</option>
    <option value="96">Nível 96</option>
    <option value="97">Nível 97</option>
    <option value="98">Nível 98</option>
    <option value="99">Nível 99</option>
    <option value="100">Nível 100</option>
    </select>
                </td>
             </tr>
             
             <tr>
                <td>
                   Exp ganha:
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input max="25" min="0" step="1" pattern="0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25" value="0" type="text" id="numero" />
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input value="Up!" type="button" id="calcular" />
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                   Níveis upados:
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input id="up" type="text" />
                </td></tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu automatizei a criação dos niveis, a cada nivel ele vai pedir 10% a mais que o anterior, e a cada 5 niveis eu faço um incremento adicional de 50%.

segue uma implementação, no caso tenho uma lista de personagens e uma lista de niveis, como no exemplo abaixo:

- nivel: 1 Next: 10 (10 + 0)
- nivel: 2 Next: 11 (10 + 1)
- nivel: 3 Next: 13 (11 + 2)
- nivel: 4 Next: 15 (13 + 2)
- nivel: 5 Next: 26 (15 + 8 + 3)
- nivel: 6 Next: 29 (25 + 3)

Depois criei alguns jogadores e deu uma exp inicial para eles.

Ao selecionar um jogador, eu busco as informações dele na nossa lista de jogadores, assim como as informações referentes ao nivel dele.

```js
//Inicio - Mock dos Niveis
var expNext = 10;
var expMin = 0;

var niveis = [];
for (var nivel = 1; nivel < 100; nivel++) {   
  if (nivel % 5 == 0) {
    expNext = Math.ceil(expNext * 1.5);
  }
  niveis.push({ 
    "nivel": nivel, //nivel atual
    "expNext": expNext, //exp para o proximo nivel
    "expMin": expMin, //exp total ao chegar neste nivel
    "expMax": expMin + expNext //exp total para o proximo nivel
  });
  expMin = expMin + expNext;
  expNext = Math.ceil(expNext * 1.1);
}
//Termino - Mock dos Niveis

//Inicio - Mock dos Personagens
var personagens = [];
for (var id = 1; id <= 5; id++) {
  var firstName = faker.name.firstName();
  var lastName = faker.name.lastName();
  var currentExp = faker.random.number(128);
  var currentNivel = niveis.filter(function (nivel) {
    return nivel.expMin < currentExp && currentExp < nivel.expMax;
  })[0];
  personagens.push({
    "id": id, //id incremental do personagem
    "nome": faker.name.findName(firstName, lastName), //nome do personagem
    "currentExp": currentExp, //exp total atual
    "currentNivel": currentNivel.nivel //nivel atual
  });
}
//Termino - Mock dos Personagens

var listPersonagens = document.getElementById("listPersonagens");
var expPersonagens = document.getElementById("expPersonagens");
var expGanha = document.getElementById("expGanha");
var expIncrementar = document.getElementById("expIncrementar");
var tmplPersonagem = document.getElementById("tmplPersonagem").innerHTML;

tmplPersonagem = Handlebars.compile(tmplPersonagem);
listPersonagens.innerHTML = tmplPersonagem(personagens);

var onListPersonagensChange = function (event) {
  var personagem = personagens.filter(function (per) {
    return per.id == listPersonagens.value;
  })[0];
  var nivel = niveis.filter(function (niv) {
    return niv.expMin < personagem.currentExp && personagem.currentExp < niv.expMax;
  })[0];
  expPersonagens.textContent = "Nivel Atual: " + nivel.nivel + " | Exp Atual: ";
  expPersonagens.textContent += (personagem.currentExp - nivel.expMin) + "/" + nivel.expNext;
};

var onExpIncrementarClick = function (event) {
  var personagem = personagens.filter(function (per) {
    return per.id == listPersonagens.value;
  })[0];

  personagem.currentExp += parseInt(expGanha.value);    
  var nivel = niveis.filter(function (niv) {
    return niv.expMin < personagem.currentExp && personagem.currentExp < niv.expMax;
  })[0];
  personagem.currentNivel = nivel.nivel;

  expPersonagens.textContent = "Nivel Atual: " + nivel.nivel + " | Exp Atual: ";
  expPersonagens.textContent += (personagem.currentExp - nivel.expMin) + "/" + nivel.expNext;
}

listPersonagens.addEventListener("change", onListPersonagensChange);
expIncrementar.addEventListener("click", onExpIncrementarClick);

onListPersonagensChange({ target: listPersonagens });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/build/build/faker.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    personagem: 
    <select id="listPersonagens">

    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="expPersonagens"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Exp Ganha: 
    <input id="expGanha" type="text" ></input>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="expIncrementar" type="button" value="Up!" />
</div>

<script id="tmplPersonagem" type="text/template">
    {{#each this}}
    <option value="{{id}}" >{{nome}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Note que toda alteração nos inputs reflete nas listas `niveis` e `personagens`.

Comment: o Seu exemplo ficou top, +1

Answer (score 1):

Comentei bem a solução, mas basicamente você precisa fazer um *loop* "passando" a **XP Ganha** para a **XP do Jogador** e verificando se a XP do Jogador é suficiente para ele passar de level, se for suba o level, se não for apenas adicione a XP Ganha à XP do Jogador:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   var levels = [0,
    10,    30,    90, 
    270,   510,   830, 
    1090,  1570,  2000,
    4000,  7000,  9999,
    15000, 20000, 50000
   ];
  
   var maximo = false;

   $("#calcular").click(function() {
     
     if (maximo){
        alert('Seu Level já está no máximo.');
        return;
     }

      // Level Atual
      var level = parseInt( $("#level").val()   );

      // Exp Atual
      var exp =   parseInt( $("#exp").val()     );

      // XP Ganha
      var xp =    parseInt( $("#numero").val()  );

      // Total de XP Ganha
      $('#exptotal').val( parseInt( $('#exptotal').val() ) + xp );

      // Levels Upados
      var levelup = 0;

      while(xp > 0){
         // Se XP ganha é maior ou igual a XP necessária para subir o level
         if ((exp + xp) >= levels[level] ){
            // Sobe de Level
            level++;
            levelup++;
            xp -= (levels[level] - exp);
            exp = 0;
           
            if (levels[level] == undefined){
               alert('Parabéns! Você atingiu o nivel máximo.');
               maximo = true;
               xp = 0;
            }
           
         } else {
            // Senão, adiciona XP ganha
            exp += xp;
            xp = 0;
         }
      }

      $("#level").val(level)

      $("#up").val(levelup);

      $("#exp").val( exp );

      $("#numero").val(0);



   });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Calibri, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  color:#000;
  font-size:11pt;
}

select {
  width:160px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
}

input {
  width:152px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
  text-align:right;
}

#calcular {
  width:160px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#666;
  color:#fff;
}

#exp {
  text-align:center;
}
#exp2 {
  text-align:center;
}
#exp3 {
  text-align:center;
}

td {
  padding-right:10px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Informe o Nível:
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="level">
            <option value="0">Noob</option>
            <option value="1">Nível 1</option>
            <option value="2">Nível 2</option>
            <option value="3">Nível 3</option>
            <option value="4">Nível 4</option>
            <option value="5">Nível 5</option>
            <option value="6">Nível 6</option>
            <option value="7">Nível 7</option>
            <option value="8">Nível 8</option>
            <option value="9">Nível 9</option>
            <option value="10">Nível 10</option>
            <option value="11">Nível 11</option>
            <option value="12">Nível 12</option>
            <option value="13">Nível 13</option>
            <option value="14">Nível 14</option>
            <option value="15">Nível 15</option>
            <option value="16">Nível 16</option>
            <option value="17">Nível 17</option>
            <option value="18">Nível 18</option>
            <option value="19">Nível 19</option>
            <option value="20">Nível 20</option>
            <option value="21">Nível 21</option>
            <option value="22">Nível 22</option>
            <option value="23">Nível 23</option>
            <option value="24">Nível 24</option>
            <option value="25">Nível 25</option>
            <option value="26">Nível 26</option>
            <option value="27">Nível 27</option>
            <option value="28">Nível 28</option>
            <option value="29">Nível 29</option>
            <option value="30">Nível 30</option>
            <option value="31">Nível 31</option>
            <option value="32">Nível 32</option>
            <option value="33">Nível 33</option>
            <option value="34">Nível 34</option>
            <option value="35">Nível 35</option>
            <option value="36">Nível 36</option>
            <option value="37">Nível 37</option>
            <option value="38">Nível 38</option>
            <option value="39">Nível 39</option>
            <option value="40">Nível 40</option>
            <option value="41">Nível 41</option>
            <option value="42">Nível 42</option>
            <option value="43">Nível 43</option>
            <option value="44">Nível 44</option>
            <option value="45">Nível 45</option>
            <option value="46">Nível 46</option>
            <option value="47">Nível 47</option>
            <option value="48">Nível 48</option>
            <option value="49">Nível 49</option>
            <option value="50">Nível 50</option>
            <option value="51">Nível 51</option>
            <option value="52">Nível 52</option>
            <option value="53">Nível 53</option>
            <option value="54">Nível 54</option>
            <option value="55">Nível 55</option>
            <option value="56">Nível 56</option>
            <option value="57">Nível 57</option>
            <option value="58">Nível 58</option>
            <option value="59">Nível 59</option>
            <option value="60">Nível 60</option>
            <option value="61">Nível 61</option>
            <option value="62">Nível 62</option>
            <option value="63">Nível 63</option>
            <option value="64">Nível 64</option>
            <option value="65">Nível 65</option>
            <option value="66">Nível 66</option>
            <option value="67">Nível 67</option>
            <option value="68">Nível 68</option>
            <option value="69">Nível 69</option>
            <option value="70">Nível 70</option>
            <option value="71">Nível 71</option>
            <option value="72">Nível 72</option>
            <option value="73">Nível 73</option>
            <option value="74">Nível 74</option>
            <option value="75">Nível 75</option>
            <option value="76">Nível 76</option>
            <option value="77">Nível 77</option>
            <option value="78">Nível 78</option>
            <option value="79">Nível 79</option>
            <option value="80">Nível 80</option>
            <option value="81">Nível 81</option>
            <option value="82">Nível 82</option>
            <option value="83">Nível 83</option>
            <option value="84">Nível 84</option>
            <option value="85">Nível 85</option>
            <option value="86">Nível 86</option>
            <option value="87">Nível 87</option>
            <option value="88">Nível 88</option>
            <option value="89">Nível 89</option>
            <option value="90">Nível 90</option>
            <option value="91">Nível 91</option>
            <option value="92">Nível 92</option>
            <option value="93">Nível 93</option>
            <option value="94">Nível 94</option>
            <option value="95">Nível 95</option>
            <option value="96">Nível 96</option>
            <option value="97">Nível 97</option>
            <option value="98">Nível 98</option>
            <option value="99">Nível 99</option>
            <option value="100">Nível 100</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Exp:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="exp" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Exp Total:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="exptotal" value="0" readonly></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                  ---------------------------------------------
              </td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Exp ganha:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input max="25" min="0" step="1" pattern="0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25" value="0" type="text" id="numero" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Up!" type="button" id="calcular" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Níveis upados:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="up" type="text" />
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

---

**Obs.:** Eu não escrevi a XP necessária para todos os níveis, mas implementei até o nível 16 e coloquei uma regra de nível máximo no código. Basta alterar a regra para que se adeque ao seu game.